# What letters should be capitalized in a "Revert to default" button?

Tags: capitalization

The question speaks for itself. I have a button on a webpage that lets the user revert to default settings. Should it be "Revert to default" or Revert to Default"?

Comment: Who cares? It's a single letter. Just make sure it's consistent with all your other buttons.

Comment: I would recommend asking this on [User Experience StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com). First and foremost, be consistent: use the same sort of capitalization as on other buttons on your site where you have more than one word.

Comment: You should have an overall policy for the web application as to whether such things receive no capitals, only initial capitals, or are treated as "titles" and "significant" words are capitalized.  I've seen it done all three ways, but it should be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

In a short phrase like that, on a button [physical or not] I don't think there are rules.  "Revert To Default" / "revert to default" / "REVERT TO DEFAULT"  it's a matter of style.